# Delete variables based on the number of observations

Tags: spss

I have an SPSS file that contains about 1000 variables and I have to delete the ones having 0 valid values. I can think of a loop with an if statement but I can't find how to write it.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be to use the `spssaux2.FindEmptyVars` Python function like this:

```
begin program.  
import spssaux2  

spssaux2.FindEmptyVars(delete=True)  
end program.
```

If you don't already have the spssaux2 module installed, you would need to get it from the SPSS Community website or the IBM Predictive Analytics site and save it in the python\lib\site-packages directory under your Statistics installation.

Otherwise, the `VALIDATEDATA` command, if you have it, will identify the variables violating such rules as maximum percentage of missing values, but you would have to turn that output into a DELETE VARIABLES command.  You could also look for variables with zero missing values using, say, `DESCRIPTIVES` and select out the ones with N=0.

Answer (score 1):

If you've never worked with python in SPSS, here's a way to get the job done without it (not as elegant, but should do the job):

This will count the valid cases in each variable, and select only those that have 0 valid cases. Then you'll manually copy the names of these variables into a syntax command that will delete them.

```
DATASET NAME Orig.
DATASET DECLARE VARLIST.
AGGREGATE /OUTFILE='VARLIST'/BREAK=
/**list_all_the_variable_names_here = NU(*FirstVarName to *LastVarName).
DATASET ACTIVATE VARLIST.
VARSTOCASES /MAKE NumValid FROM *FirstVarName to *LastVarName/INDEX=VarName(NumValid).
SELECT IF NumValid=0.
EXECUTE.
```

Pause here to copy the remaining names in the list and complete the syntax, then continue:

```
DATASET ACTIVATE Orig.
DELETE VARIABLES *paste_here_all_the_remaining_variable_names_from_varlist .
```

Notes:
* I put stars where you have to replace my text with your variable names.
** If the variables are neatly named like Q1, Q2, Q3 .... Q1000, you can use the "FirstVarName to LastVarName" form (Q1 to Q1000) instead of listing all the variable names.

BTW it is of course possible to do this completely automatically without manually copying those names (using only syntax, no Python), but the added complexity is not worth bothering with for a single use...